# Could I use Capybara on frameworks outside Rails (PHP)?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, magento, capybara

I would like to test my php web app (specifically Magento) with Capybara. I've used Capybara with success when I used rails before so I want to replicate the success. Does anyone know if this is possible or maybe there is a Capybara for php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You have to define the url where your server serves the pages you want to test. For example, if you use `rspec` simply do it in the `spec_helper.rb`. Additionally you have to specify a different driver that does not want to start the app (which is not present), for example `selenium`:

```
Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.site-to-test.com' # where your site lives
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium # use selenium to control the external browsers
```

A basic `Gemfile` would look like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "rspec", '~> 3.0'
gem "capybara"
gem "selenium-webdriver", '~> 2.45'
```

If you run your tests, it will fire up the browser window (if your browser is installed in some non default path you will have to configure this, too), will open your page and interact with it.

Comment: sorry, i'm just a little confused on the driver. why do i need selenium? I'm guessing its because if this was all on local, i would be running two servers?

Comment: The default driver tries to start a local rack app, which you do not have (because you have a php app). The selenium driver does not try to start any app and it controls external browsers. So you need to a) start your php server and b) set the `app_host` to where it serves the pages (can be `http://localhost` if it is local)